# error[E0463]: can't find crate for `profiler_builtins` with -Zprofile flag in rustup for armv7a-none-eabi

Tags: rust, embedded, code-coverage

I am trying to get the coverage data of my rust code for an armv7a-none-eabi target. Building the code for x86 works without much trouble, but I am unable to build it for my armv7a-none-eabi target. I get the error:

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `profiler_builtins`
```

The command I am using to compile is:

```
RUSTFLAGS="-Zprofile" cargo +nightly build --target="armv7a-none-eabi"
```

Its a bare metal no-std project.

With incremental compilation already disabled.
I've found an issue tracking all the development related to this flag, but from what I understand it should be working even if it is unstable (https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42524).

Is there something I am missing? Is there a way to build the profiler_builtins manually and point to it with an env variable or config?

Minimal reproducible example:
create a new cargo project with the main.rs file:

```rust
#![no_std]
#![no_main]
use core::panic::PanicInfo;

#[panic_handler]
fn panic_handler(info: &PanicInfo) -> ! {
    loop {}
}

pub extern fn main() {}
```

compile with: `RUSTFLAGS="-Zprofile" cargo +nightly build --target="armv7a-none-eabi"`

Expected result: Code compiles with gcov profiling.
Actual result: code does not compile: `` error[E0463]: can't find crate for `profiler_builtins ``

#### rustc verison:

- rustc 1.78.0-nightly (2bf78d12d 2024-02-18)
- binary: rustc
- commit-hash: 2bf78d12d33ae02d10010309a0d85dd04e7cff72
- commit-date: 2024-02-18
- host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
- release: 1.78.0-nightly
- LLVM version: 18.1.0